# Best User Experience with a low scoring result with Google reCaptcha v3?

Tags: html, recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

**How did you implement a good User Experience with a low scoring number using Google reCaptcha v3?**

---

The best answer I have found is [reCaptcha v3 handle score callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52334269/recaptcha-v3-handle-score-callback) but I still need a more UX friendly way of handling this.

Google recommends 2 form verification or email validation. Both of those seem far more evasive than "find all the stop signs in these images"

My first thought was to use v2, but it would be nice to not hinder the user. Then I thought about appending my own "I am not a robot" checkbox to the form and have some additional validation when they fail... but then the reCaptcha fails again and the user is stuck in a loop.

Does anyone have feedback on the best way to handle v3 results? Do you have some examples or ideas?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. You have to make decisions server side on the score they have. The user doesn't need to do anything.

Comment: Let me edit that response... When you make a decision server side, what do you do with the user when the score is low? Just assume they are a robot and don't let them submit? What feedback do you give the user? What if they are a legitimate user? Then they are stuck.

Comment: The recommendations are to do two factor auth or email validation. Okay, so now I have to re-route the user? Tell them to go check their email... that is bad user experience. It's much better to just use v2 I think, but prove me wrong. How should a fail result be handled in v3?

Comment: Okay, I understand what you mean. But I can't help you with this. I am very bad at these things

Comment: That's fine, thanks for trying.