# How do I fake a recaptcha in a unit test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, controller, recaptcha

I'm using Rails 5 and have a form with a Google recaptcha.  I use the Rails gem for this

```
gem "recaptcha", require: "recaptcha/rails"
```

So I have a simple form with

```
<%= form_for @comment, :html => {:class => "commentsForm"} do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description, 'Your Comments' %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </div>
  <%= recaptcha_tags %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= submit_tag 'Submit', :class => 'btn-feedback' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

and my controller to deal with this is

```
  def create
    @comment = Comment.new(params[:comment].permit(:description))
    @comment.user = current_user
    if verify_recaptcha(model: @comment)
```

but how do I write a unit test to test the controller method?  I don't know how to "fake" the recaptcha submission.  This is all I have

```
  test "do submit comment" do
    post comments_url, params: { comment: { description: "Some comments"} }

    # Verify we got the proper response
    assert_response :success
  end
```

but this fails.  How do I fake a recaptcha in a unit test?

Comment: The gem should be disabled in the test environment. https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha#testing

Comment: Otherwise you can add a check `@comment.errors.add(:base, "Invalid Captcha") unless Rails.env.test? || verify_recaptcha(model: @comment)`

Comment: @max, you were right, it does validate in a test environment (for some reason my environment wasn't getting set to test when I ran it)

Answer (score 22):

**FOR V2 Only:**

With the following test keys, you will always get No CAPTCHA and all verification requests will pass.

**Site key:** 6LeIxAcTAAAAAJcZVRqyHh71UMIEGNQ_MXjiZKhI

**Secret key:** 6LeIxAcTAAAAAGG-vFI1TnRWxMZNFuojJ4WifJWe

Source: [Google reCAPTCHA FAQs Page](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq)

Comment: Does it still call the service though? Thats something that you may want to avoid in tests.

Comment: This does not work for v3, as noted in the documentation.

Comment: yes, It looks like you have to create a separate key for the testing environment for v3.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean with "faking". If it is about getting a verification return with a low score (i.e. high robot probability), you could spoof the User Agent, if this is possible in your test routine.

See this answer on SO : [Is it possible to force fail a recaptcha v2 for testing purposes? (I.e. pretend to be a robot)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43397678/is-it-possible-to-force-fail-a-recaptcha-v2-for-testing-purposes-i-e-pretend)